# Postgres multiple SQL-Statements do not stop when an error occurs

Tags: postgresql

I have multiple Insert Statementes:

```
INSERT INTO table1(item_name) VALUES ('item1');
INSERT INTO table1(item_name) VALUES ('item2');
INSERT INTO table1(item_name) VALUES ('item3');
```

the first value already exists in the table. So i get an error: `ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint` when the first statement is executed and the execution of the other statements stops.

How can i force Postgres to execute the other statements despite the error? I know that INSERT ON CONFLICT in this case would be a solution, my question is more general: How to continue with the following statements if an error occurs.

Comment: Just to clarify, from where exactly are you executing this block of insert statements?

Comment: the query editor in pgadmin

Answer (score 0):

If you send several SQL statements, separated by semicolon, to the PostgreSQL server in a single query, they are executed in a single transaction. So if one of them fails, all are undone and processing terminates.

You have to execute each statement separately for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `psql` CLI instead of pgadmin, you can use `ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK` setting.

> When set to on, if a statement in a transaction block generates an
>   error, the error is ignored and the transaction continues. When set to
>   interactive, such errors are only ignored in interactive sessions, and
>   not when reading script files. When set to off (the default), a
>   statement in a transaction block that generates an error aborts the
>   entire transaction. The error rollback mode works by issuing an
>   implicit SAVEPOINT for you, just before each command that is in a
>   transaction block, and then rolling back to the savepoint if the
>   command fails.

Example:

```
select * from t;
 x 
---
 1
(1 row)

\set ON_ERROR_ROLLBACK on

begin;
BEGIN

insert into t values(1);
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "t_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (x)=(1) already exists.

insert into t values(2);
INSERT 0 1

insert into t values(3);
INSERT 0 1

commit;
COMMIT

select * from t;
 x 
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```